# Find the smallest possible integer $y$ such that $288y$ is a multiple of $5616$

Tags: prime-factorization, integers

> Find the smallest possible integer $y$ such that $288y$ is a multiple of $5616$

$$288 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3$$

$$5616 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 13$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$288 = 2^5 \times 3^2$, and $5616=2^4 \times 3^3 \times 13$.

Therefore, we have that the LCM is $2^5 \times 3^3 \times 13$.

Dividng by $288$ to get $y = 3 \times 13=\boxed{39}$

Comment: Do you know why the LCM is the max of each prime factor?

Comment: I think this answer would be more transparent without referencing the LCM at all, and just look at the prime factorisations (keeping in mind how to tell from prime factorisations when one number divides another). You clearly need to add a $3$ and a $13$ to the prime factorisation of $288$ to make it divisible by $5616$.

Answer (score 2):

We want $5616 \mid 288 y$. This is possible if $288y$ contains all the prime factors from $5616$.

Using your factorizations (I did not check them):
\begin{align}
288  &= 2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot3\\
5616 &= 2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot13
\end{align}
and realigning a bit
\begin{align}
288  &= 2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot3\\
5616 &= 2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot1\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot13
\end{align}
we see that we just lack the factors $3$ and $13$ in the factors of $288$ to have all the needed factors for $5616$.

Thus $y = 3 \cdot 13$. We used no uneeded factors, so this number is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

We want $5616n=288y$, where $n,y\in N$ and $y\to min.$

Reducing we get $y=\frac{39n}{2}$. Since $y$ and $n$ are proportional, min $y$ means min $n=2$, consequently $y=39$.